# Using WHERE on a WP_Query

Tags: wp-query

I have two custom post types: **Books** and **Subjects**. For this projects, I'm using Super-CPT to create custom post types:

```
$books = new Super_Custom_Post_Type( 'book', '', 'book', $register = array(
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
        )
);

$subjects= new Super_Custom_Post_Type( 'subject', '', '', $register = array(
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor'),
        'hierarchical' => true,
        ) 
);
```

To select which are the subjects of the book, I create a meta box and the values from Subjects:

```
$profissionais->add_meta_box( array(
        'id' => 'subjects',
        'context' => 'side',
        'fields' => array(
              'subjects' => array( 'type' => 'select', 'label' => '', 'data' => 'subject', 'multiple' => 'multiple' )
        )
) );
```

Now, I need to show on the page of each subject, the books with this subject. I start with this:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'book',
);
$books = new WP_Query($args);
```

But I do not know how to move forward. I'm trying to do something like this:

```
SELECT book_title FROM books WHERE subject = subject page title
```

**UPDATE**

Solved!

```
$current = get_the_ID();

 $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'book',
   'posts_per_page' => -1,
   'meta_key' => 'subjects',
   'meta_value' => $current,
 );

 $books = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: How does "Super-CPT" store those fields? Post meta?

Comment: @s_ha_dum The fields are store in wp_postmeta table: meta_key: subjects; meta_value: 78. This is the subject id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you need something like the following:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'book',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'subject',
    'meta_value' => YOUR_SUBJECT_PAGE_TITLE,
);
$books = new WP_Query($args);
```

Is this what you're trying to achieve?

Also, please have a look at [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).